# ColdFusion RecordCount as multiple conditional

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, record-count

I would like to run one query + output and in case no records exist run second query + output and in case both have no records then redirected to

```
<test1.RecordCount eq 0>
```

but the problem is that I can only use one `<cfelse>`

Any idea?

The Code for one query + output and RecordCount

```
<cfif test1.RecordCount eq 0>
    <!--- Display some message.--->
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput query="test1">
        <!--- Display some other message --->
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Other tags you might find useful are `<cfelseif>` and `<cfswitch>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to use nested `<cfif ...>` conditions.

Something like:

```
<cfif test1.RecordCount gt 0>
    <cfoutput query="test1">
        <!--- Display test1 query results --->
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfif test2.RecordCount gt 0>
        <cfoutput query="test2">
            <!--- Display test2 query results --->
        </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
        <!--- Display some message.--->
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Or you could use `<cfelseif>` like this:

```
<cfif test1.RecordCount gt 0>
    <cfoutput query="test1">
        <!--- Display test1 query results --->
    </cfoutput>
<cfelseif test2.RecordCount gt 0>
    <cfoutput query="test2">
        <!--- Display test2 query results --->
    </cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <!--- Display some message.--->
</cfif>
```

Comment: We don't need `<cfif test1.RecordCount gt 0>` , instead we can able to check `<cfif test1.RecordCount>`. this will also work.

Comment: @jawaharN while you are correct that the additional text is not needed I included that in my answer because it helps to better illustrate what is actually happening. If I did not include the `gt 0` portion someone might mistakenly think that `RecordCount` returns a boolean, which it does not.